# Change url on modal load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I'm using twitter bootstrap and laravel to create a web application. The issue I seem to be having is that my sign in and register routines take place on the same page '/'. I am attempting to change the url when the modals load so that I can use routes from two different locations.

Here are my routes

```
Route::post('register', array('uses' =>'RegistrationController@doRegister'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'RegistrationController@doLogin'));
```

Here are the modals

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign In</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" method="post" id="signInForm">
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                    <div class="row"><!-- Input for Sign In-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="User ID">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- End of Input for Sign In-->
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="signInModalButton">Submit</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



 <div class="modal fade" id="registeringModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register</h4>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post" id="registerForm">
                    <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <div class="row"><!--Input for Registering-->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="addressLine1" id="addressLine1" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Address Line 1" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="addressLine2" id="addressLine2" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Address Line 2" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="City" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"><!--State Dropdown-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="state" class="form-control" tabindex="6">
                                            <option value=" " disabled selected>State</option>
                                            <option value="AL">AL</option>
                                            <option value="AK">AK</option>
                                            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                                            <option value="AR">AR</option>
                                            <option value="CA">CA</option>
                                            <option value="CO">CO</option>
                                            <option value="CT">CT</option>
                                            <option value="DE">DE</option>
                                            <option value="DC">DC</option>
                                            <option value="FL">FL</option>
                                            <option value="GA">GA</option>
                                            <option value="HI">HI</option>
                                            <option value="ID">ID</option>
                                            <option value="IL">IL</option>
                                            <option value="IN">IN</option>
                                            <option value="IA">IA</option>
                                            <option value="KS">KS</option>
                                            <option value="KY">KY</option>
                                            <option value="LA">LA</option>
                                            <option value="ME">ME</option>
                                            <option value="MD">MD</option>
                                            <option value="MA">MA</option>
                                            <option value="MI">MI</option>
                                            <option value="MN">MN</option>
                                            <option value="MS">MS</option>
                                            <option value="MO">MO</option>
                                            <option value="MT">MT</option>
                                            <option value="NE">NE</option>
                                            <option value="NV">NV</option>
                                            <option value="NH">NH</option>
                                            <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                                            <option value="NM">NM</option>
                                            <option value="NY">NY</option>
                                            <option value="NC">NC</option>
                                            <option value="ND">ND</option>
                                            <option value="OH">OH</option>
                                            <option value="OK">OK</option>
                                            <option value="OR">OR</option>
                                            <option value="PA">PA</option>
                                            <option value="RI">RI</option>
                                            <option value="SC">SC</option>
                                            <option value="SD">SD</option>
                                            <option value="TN">TN</option>
                                            <option value="TX">TX</option>
                                            <option value="UT">UT</option>
                                            <option value="VT">VT</option>
                                            <option value="VA">VA</option>
                                            <option value="WA">WA</option>
                                            <option value="WV">WV</option>
                                            <option value="WI">WI</option>
                                            <option value="WY">WY</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--End of State Dropdown List-->
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Zipcode" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div><!-- End of input for registering-->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="registerModalButton">Register</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I use this javascript to submit the forms

```
    //Delay JS bind so button exists                           
 $(document).ready(function() {                 $('#signInModalButton').click(function() {                    $('#signInForm').submit();
 }); }); </script>
```

EDIT: For clarification /login and /register pages do not exist I'm trying to change the url when the modal appears so that my routes work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The action attributes in the forms are empty. That's why your forms are being submitted to the same page.

You need to replace

`<form action="" method="post" id="signInForm">`

with

`<form action="{{ URL::to('register') }}" method="post" id="signInForm">`

and

`<form action="" method="post" id="signInForm">`

with

`<form action="{{ URL::to('login') }}" method="post" id="signInForm">`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: Does this still redirect to the same page or some error is being displayed?

Comment: I get this error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: This should be right! Without actions your posts are going nowhere without AJAX.

Comment: @Matt There's something wrong somewhere in your code. You need to enable debug in the application configuration and you'll see the errors in your code.

Comment: @SUB0DH I've enabled debugging in the app.php config but that's the most descriptive error that it is giving me.

Comment: I think I've nailed down the issue the pages /login and /register don't exist I'm trying to change the URL when the modals appear.

Comment: If you think, the problem is with the routes, you can use absoulte URL for the register and login actions by passing them to the `URL::to` method. I have changed my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: You are correct my route 

`Route::get('overview', function()
{
 return  View::make('overview');
});`

Doesn't return any views. Even if I change overview to index. Thanks for the help.

So going to http://myapp.com/overview doesn't return any data.

Comment: If you have not properly configured `.htaccess`, you might need to go to http://myapp.com/public/overview . If you have not enabled mod_rewrite on the server, you need to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button are wrong for as far as I can see. Should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="signInModalButton">Submit</button>
```

They should also be placed inside your `<form>` and your forms should have an action on it.

Comment: I have some javascript that handles the  submit


`<script type='text/javascript'>
   //Delay JS bind so button exists
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signInModalButton').click(function() {
     $('#signInForm').submit();
    });
   });
   </script>`

Comment: Ok I think it's a good idea to provide all all that to the question, otherwise people will not be able to help you. Maybe I can help you with that? ;) Otherwise people will flag it and your question will be closed.